# How to typedef a smart pointer wrapping a template class

Tags: templates, c++11, typedef, smart-pointers

How can I typedef a `std::unique_ptr<T>`, where `T` is a template class `Object<U>`?

I have a template class, Object.h:

```
    template<typename T>
    class Object
    {
    public:
       Object()                      {}
       ~Object()                     {}

       T getValue()                  { return value_; }
       void setValue(T value)        { value_ = value; }

    private:
       T value_;
    }
```

And another class called Holder, which holds an Object wrapped in a smart pointer, `std::unique_ptr<Object<T>>`, in a container:

```
    template<typename T>
    class Holder
    {
    public:
       Holder()                      {}
       ~Holder()                     {}

    private:
       std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object<T>>> objects_;
    }
```

I always use typedefs to refer to objects wrapped in smart pointers, so I put the following typedef in the class definition:

```
    template<typename T>
    class Holder
    {
       typedef std::unique_ptr<Object<T>> ObjectPtr; // - (1)
      // using  ObjectPtr = std::unique_ptr<T, Object<T>> - (2) alias template - same error as above
      // typedef std::unique_ptr<Object<T>> ObjectPtr<T> - not allowed
      // ..

     private:
        std::vector<ObjectPtr<T>> objects_;
```

However, changing the type of member variable `objects_` to `ObjectPtr<T>` results in the compiler error `C2947: expecting ´>´ to terminate template-argument-list, found ´<´`.

What is the correct method to do this?

Comment: You don't really want to parametrize the type really? don't you? also ";" is essential termination to class definition in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct about what you want to achieve, a solution would be to declare an [alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

```
template<typename T>
class Holder
{
public:
    template<typename U>
    using ObjectPtr = std::unique_ptr<Object<U>>;

    void add_objet(ObjectPtr<T> newObject)
    { objects_.emplace_back(std::move(newObject)); }

private:
    std::vector<ObjectPtr<T>> objects_;
};

int main()
{
    Holder<int> holder;
    holder.add_objet( make_unique<Object<int>>() );
}
```

**EDIT**

Because my solution defines an inner-template within the main template, it's overkill and somewhat cumbersome: within the main template, each use of ObjectPtr must be parameterized by T. See the typedef-based solutions proposed below by other contributors for a simpler solution.

Comment: I want to have a unique pointer wrapping an Object, and a collection of them: `using ObjectPtr = std::unique_ptr<ObjectPtr<T>>` and then: `std::vector<Object<T>>`.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear on that point. This code sample should be the good one

Comment: Works well, thanks. I was missing the inclusion of `template<typename T>` before my template alias. I wonder why it must be included again when it refers already to the same type as the class.

Comment: @KoolBananna: In Daniel's solution, it doesn't refer the the same type argument as the class.  (See my clarifying edit).

Comment: Full agreement with Ben, my solution is an overkill, and his solution is simpler. I'm going to do some editing to show why.

Comment: @Daniel: You can get rid of redundantly naming the type by using `emplace_back` instead... although that creates leak potential if the vector append throws an exception.  Overall, it's better for the function parameter itself to also be a smart pointer.

Comment: @Ben: You're right to point this out. I just wanted to demontrate that my proposal defines an entity (template<T> template<U> ObjectPtr) which is more complex and combersome than needed.

Comment: @Ben: there's a problem with your example actually. Right now, It doesn't compile because the ctor for unique_ptrs is explicit. I'm not sure which way you'd want to correct that, so I'll let you do it, and I'll duplicate in my example.

Comment: @DanielStrul: You're right, I often forget some of the implications of that.  Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably all you want is:

```
template<typename T>
class Holder
{
   typedef std::unique_ptr<Object<T>> ObjectPtr; // - (1)

   void add_object( ObjectPtr newObject )
   { objects_.emplace_back(std::move(newObject)); }

 private:
    std::vector<ObjectPtr> objects_;
};

int main()
{
    Holder<int> holder;
    holder.add_object(make_unique<Object<int>>());
}
```

Note that `Holder<T>::ObjectPtr` doesn't need an argument of its own, because it uses the `T` from the containing class.

Answer (score 1):

Within the class definition there is no need for the defined typedef to be parametrized with the typename T when referenced , just replace ObjectPtr directly:

Does not work:

```
std::vector<ObjectPtr<T>> objects_;
```

Works:

```
std::vector<ObjectPtr> objects_;
```